# Devise + Carrierwave crop image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, carrierwave, crop

I'm trying to update existing user avatar with cropped image. Also controller gets all needed params(avatar_crop_x, avatar_crop_y, avatar_crop_w, avatar_crop_h). I've permitted them in `devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update)` method.

```
Started PATCH "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-23 23:50:29 +0300
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"n8ZQYS5iZXJs6V5eS4PfJKDeUhugasvXXIvIP+ZZIyLV4tukuqqjSvUA
+DnZFZSF468eam1vSF8hD5STYmeA8Q==", "user"=>{"email"=>"admin@example.com", "username"=>"admin", "first_name"=>"",
                                            "last_name"=>"", "position"=>"", "city"=>"", "bio"=>"",
                                            "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f82cb8f3860
# @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/2h/4k0zwm8s4j1dfq5_8zf7ttmr0000gn/T/RackMultipart20170723-11835-fia4di.jpg>,
# @original_filename="gloomy-mountain-lake-hd-wallpaper.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg",
# @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\"; filename=\"gloomy-mountain-lake-hd-wallpaper
# .jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "avatar_crop_x"=>"1266.6666666666665", "avatar_crop_y"=>"319
# .9999999999999", "avatar_crop_w"=>"1280", "avatar_crop_h"=>"1280", "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
# "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Update"}
```

Also I've four fields in User model.

```
class User 
...
attr_accessor :avatar_crop_x, :avatar_crop_y, :avatar_crop_w, :avatar_crop_h
...
```

But in my uploader all `model.avatar_crop_*` fields are nil.

```
class AvatarUploader < BaseUploader
  process :crop

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [50, 50]
  end

  def crop
    if model.avatar_crop_x.present?
      manipulate! do |img|
        w = model.avatar_crop_w.to_i
        h = model.avatar_crop_h.to_i

        # Set x-y coordinates of cropped image.
        x = model.avatar_crop_x.to_i
        y = model.avatar_crop_y.to_i
        img.crop "#{w}x#{h}+#{x}+#{y}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Does anybody have the same issue? Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Could you add more information about the cropping method and how you send `:avatar_crop_x, :avatar_crop_y, :avatar_crop_w, :avatar_crop_h` to the uploader?

Comment: @Jeremie I use cropper.js https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper instead of JCrop. I have four hidden fields in my form, when I submit the form params send to Devise::RegistarationController#update. You could see the log above. I don't understand why model in avatar uploader have fields with nil values. This `model.avatar_crop_w` returns nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure before `avatar` is set you have set cropping params.

For eg:

This doesn't make height available in uploader:

`User.new(avatar: file, height: "10px")`

This does:

`User.new(height: "10px", avatar: file)`

Check order where you are permitting params.

Comment: Yeah it works! Thanks. Please, could you explain why does it happen?

Comment: the uploader functionality gets called as assignment happens. So in first case, by the time assignment of `avatar` happens the `height` is not assigned to the `user` object.